# How to correctly import RAW 16bit in DigiKam

Tags: software, raw, import

I am trying to edit raw 16bit images in DigiKam. The photos are .NEF taken with a Nikon D5300. No matter how much I fiddle with the Raw Import Tool my images look darker, redish and have low contrast (see image [1]). The preview looks good, however. What is the correct way to decode raw 16 bit images?

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dw9q.jpg

Comment: I haven't used digiKam, so this question is from normal raw process point of view. How do the settings in the Post Processing tab look like? Usually that is where you need to tweak to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are handling RAW files. Obviously the picture in DigiKam will not match the preview image, having a fixed white balance, contrast, etc. RAW images store far more dynamic range than a JPEG does, too. You have to process the RAW image, using curves or all the available controls to arrive at a pleasing picture. There is nothing wrong with your "decoding" of raw images, your job of post-processing starts here.

If you are new to RAW post-processing, maybe you should try Lightroom to have a taste of what you can accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If importing 16 bit RAW in DigiKam you might want to consider generating and using color profiles for your camera.

[Digikam: Why are my RAW images so dark?](http://www.digikam.org/node/273)

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought Nikon D3300 and raw support was not there under linux (which I use). Now [Darktable](http://darktable.org) does support it. You can try that. 
The discussion is at [Flickr group](https://secure.flickr.com/groups/darktable/discuss/72157643199196944/). I have not tried Digicam.

The photos [here](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/sridharma/sets/72157644466131046/) were processed with Darktable and stitched using Hugin.